# Understanding the proof of the fact that the Chow group of a scheme $X$ is graded by dimension.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, schemes, intersection-theory

I would like to understand the proof of this fact:

If $X$ is a scheme (separated, of finite type over $k=\overline{k}$) then the Chow group of $X$ is graded by dimension; that is,
\begin{equation}
A(X)=\oplus A_k(x)
\end{equation}
with $A_k(x)$ the group of rational equivalence classes of $k$-cycles.
In the proof it is said that if $\Phi \subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times_{k} X$ is an irreducible variety (not contained in a fiber over $X$) then, in an appropriate affine open set $\Phi \cap (\mathbb{A}^1\ \times X) \subset \Phi$, the scheme $\Phi \cap(\{t_0\} \times X)$ is defined  by the vanishing of the single nonzerodivisor $t-t_0$. It follows that the components of this intersection are all of codimension exactly $1$ in $\Phi$, and similarly for $\Phi \cap (\{t_1\} \times X)$.

I don't understand why $\Phi \cap (\mathbb{A}^1 \times X)$ is affine, and i cannot see the fact "*the scheme $\Phi \cap(\{t_0\} \times X)$ is defined  by the vanishing of the single nonzerodivisor $t-t_0$*": it should mean that the intersection above is defined by an ideal generated by one element (i.e. $t-t_0$), but why?

In the final part i would use the Corollary 2.5.26 of Liu's Algebraic geometry and Arithmetic Curves.

Maybe the question seems stupid, but i cannot see those things.

EDIT: the proof is given on "3264 and all that" of Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: The second part suggests that, since $\Phi \cap (\mathbb{A}^1 \times X)$ is affine, for $t_0\in\Bbb{A}^1$ the subscheme $\Phi \cap(\{t_0\} \times X)$ is defined by $(t-t_0)$.

Comment: @Servaes Why is $\Phi \cap (\mathbb{A}^1 \times X)$ affine?

Comment: If $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $\Phi$ is all of $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ then it certainly doesn't need to be affine (either as a variety or over $\mathbb{A}^1$).